# How to get top 20 rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this database setup on `records` table

[image]

i want to PDO for the last 20 by the reference, this is an auto increment number by php but i need an sql statement that would pull out the top 20 meaning the recent 20 records

so far..

```
SELECT TOP 20
FROM records
ORDER BY reference DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LIMIT <offset>, <recordcount>`

```
SELECT * FROM records
ORDER BY reference DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: what is offset? is it a starting point? and 20 is to pull out 20? is this pulling out the last records in ie top  20 references? thanks btw

Comment: with offset you can start a defined offset. Say you want to fetch the record 10 to 19. then use offset `10,10`. If you get the last or first records can be influenced by the sort order: `desc` gets the last and `asc` the first records sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the **`LIMIT`** Keyword

```
 $display_query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT *
                FROM records
            ORDER BY reference DESC LIMIT 20");
        $display_query->execute();
        echo $display_query->fetchAll();
```

`TOP` keyword is used in **`ORACLE`** , `LIMIT` should be used on **`MySQL`**